# How do I extract Python class/method as fragments?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I am using VuePress for documentation, but find the more precise formatting and support for Python code in reStructured Text useful at times.

How can I use Sphinx and/or reStructuredText to generate fragments of HTML that I will later integrate?

How can I programmatically drive Sphinx autodoc directives is basically what my question is about. I saw something from 2003 about Sphinx parts, but what's the current way to do it?

#### Example:

given file **test.rst**:

```
######
.. autoclass:: mymodule.MyClass
    :members:  __init__, process


######
```

And **mymodule.py**

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ init """

    def process(self, f_out : "file"):
        "process"
        print("I am processing")
```

I can generate html documentation with

`sphinx-build -a . ./out`

and opening the generated **out/test.html** gives me:

[image]

where the part that I am interested in is really only:

```
<dl class="class">
    <dt id="mymodule.MyClass">
        <em class="property">class </em><code class="sig-prename descclassname">mymodule.</code><code
            class="sig-name descname">MyClass</code><span class="sig-paren">(</span><em class="sig-param">*args</em>,
        <em class="sig-param">**kwargs</em><span class="sig-paren">)</span><a class="headerlink"
            href="#mymodule.MyClass" title="Permalink to this definition">¶</a></dt>
    <dd>
✂️✂️✂️✂️
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: "something from 2003 about Sphinx parts". What is that? Sphinx did not exist in 2003.

Comment: @mzjn Must have been just rst itself then.  [Here it is](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/193890-using-rest-restructuredtext-to-create-html-snippet/)  Point is, nothing really recent seems to be around and while I see the value of rst's integration with Python, I really prefer Markdown, even with its shortcomings, most of the time.